# Can I typeset greek letters in text mode using Latin Modern Fonts?

Tags: greek, latin-modern

I use lualatex and utf8 source. I want to use the Latin Modern fonts (including math). If I include e.g. the character ε in my source file; it does not appear in the output. I've tried changing the font to TeX Gyre Pagella (with fontspec) and the ε appears as I want. I assume the Latin Modern font I'm using does not support greek characters.

Now; obviously someone has created greek glyphs for Latin Modern Math, so I'm surprised the text mode greek letters are incomplete in Latin Modern. Is there anything wrong with doing e.g.

```
\setmainfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
```

or some other hacky workaround? Is there just no way of typesetting greek characters in text mode with Latin Modern? I don't want to have to surround *every* greek letter with $$

(I appreciate the irony of trying to write greek letters with a font that has *latin* in the name, but I'm surprised the solution isn't more obvious)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}
This text appears fine.
The following does not, only the capital omega appears: ∆πΩε.
This math does appear as expected, however: $∆πΩε$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not use *math* symbols to type a *text* in greek. That's only acceptable if you need very few greek chars. And no: Latin modern doesn't cover greek - as it doesn't cover hebrew, chinese and a lot of other script. You will have to switch to another font at least for greek. A matching font could be the otf version of the computer modern fonts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Latin Modern fonts don't have the full set of Greek letters, but only some of them.

If you need only some Greek words, you can benefit from the `ucharclasses` package, as shown in the example. If you need longer passages in Greek, it's convenient to load Polyglossia.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[Latin,Greek]{ucharclasses}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Roman}

\newfontfamily{\gfsartemisia}{GFS Artemisia}
\newfontfamily{\gfsbaskerville}{GFS Baskerville}
\newfontfamily{\gfsbodoni}{GFS Bodoni}
\newfontfamily{\gfsdidot}{GFS Didot}
\newfontfamily{\cmu}{CMU Serif}

\newcommand{\greekfont}{\gfsartemisia}


\setTransitionsForLatin{}{}
\setTransitionsForGreek{\begingroup\greekfont}{\endgroup}

\begin{document}
GFS Artemisia -- This text appears fine: ΔπΩε. And again.

\renewcommand{\greekfont}{\gfsbaskerville}
GFS Baskerville -- This text appears fine: ΔπΩε. And again.

\renewcommand{\greekfont}{\gfsbodoni}
GFS Bodoni -- This text appears fine: ΔπΩε. And again.

\renewcommand{\greekfont}{\gfsdidot}
GFS Didot -- This text appears fine: ΔπΩε. And again.

\renewcommand{\greekfont}{\cmu}
CMU Serif --This text appears fine: ΔπΩε. And again.

\end{document}
```

After you've chosen the font that suits you (maybe experimenting with other Greek fonts), give it directly the name of `\greekfont`.

[image]